# Object hierarchy implementation in game engine

Tags: c++, tree

I am working on a hobby game engine, and I have currently these classes: (simplified)

```
class Scene {
    GameObject* m_root;
    GameObject*[] m_gameObjects[];
}

class GameObject {
    GameObject* m_parent;
    GameObject*[] m_children;
}
```

**Current implementation:**

- When I add a game object to the scene, I also add it as a children of the m_root, and also add it to the scene's array of game objects.

**First question:**

- As I said, currently I also store the game objects' pointers in an array so I could iterate through them easily.
- Should I maintain this array too or should I just go through the tree from the root in a while cycle?
- Which one is better for standard usage? (like calling all objects' update, searching an object, etc)

**Second question:**

- How should I access the root from a specific game object?
- Should I store the root as a static field in the GameObject class when I construct the root?
- or should I just go through the parents until I find an object which has no parent?

What I mean by going through the parent:

```
GameObject* root = this;
while(root->GetParent() != null) {
     root = root->GetParent();
}
return root;
```

I sense that the "going through the tree" method is better in both situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**
If the only usage for the array is iterating through the objects, then I'd say it's redundant. If the indices to the array have some meaning and it would allow you to access specific object faster, then there might be some benefit.

**Second question**
I'd steer completely clear of mutable class static variables. They're essentially equivalent to globals.